# Leaflet gives javascript error after rendering

Tags: leaflet, angular

I get javascript errors but the map is visible without any problems. My code

ts file

```
options = {
layers: [
  tileLayer("https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/alidade_smooth/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png",{
    maxZoom: 2,
    minZoom: 2,
    noWrap: true,
  })
],
zoom: 2,
zoomControl: false,
center: latLng(49.3824, 18.1055),
};
```

HTML

```
<div id='map'
  style="height: 100vh"
  leaflet
  [leafletOptions]="options"
  (leafletMapReady)="onMapReady($event)"
></div>
```

Any ideas why?

[image]

Comment: Those aren't errors they are tiles that don't exist

Comment: Ah... ok... Thank you